# Localising the Search Region of Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I made a google Map and someone noticed that if you type, say "Brighton" into the search, it takes the user to the USA Brighton - what's desired is the UK's Brighton.

I went to the Google Docs page for it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Region

And tried to amend my script url to:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SECRET_KEY&callback=initMap&region=GB"></script>
```

but performing the "Brighton" search still takes me to the USA.

What am I doing wrong? Tried in a private window to ensure it wasn't a cache thing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this script in particular loads the map on the page load, I have a function for searching the user's entered data which appeared like this:

```
# get lat lng values based on postcode / address
$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. urlencode($data['address']) .'&sensor=false&key=SECRET_KEY');
$geo = json_decode($geo, true);
```

Adding the `&region=GB` param here makes it work with user search.

```
# get lat lng values based on postcode / address
$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. urlencode($data['address']) .'&sensor=false&key=SECRET_KEY&region=GB');
$geo = json_decode($geo, true);
```